# calculate count from value of column based on group

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I would like to plot the count of zero or 3 in column outcome based on hours and time of column time. I have search some code that I can groupby time hour and time. But how can I apply count the value of zero or 3 based on group?

```
group = result.groupby(by=[result.event_dt.map(lambda x : x.hour), result.event_dt.map(lambda x : x.minute)])


                  time        outcome
2017-05-31 03:34:04           3
2017-05-31 03:34:04           3
2017-05-31 04:11:30           3
2017-05-31 04:42:22           3
2017-05-31 05:18:18           3
2017-05-31 05:18:18           0
2017-05-31 06:44:13           3
2017-05-31 06:44:13           3
2017-05-31 09:12:20           3
2017-05-31 09:12:20           0
2017-05-31 09:12:20           3
2017-05-31 09:12:20           0
2017-05-31 09:12:20           0
2017-05-31 09:12:20           0
2017-05-31 09:12:20           3
2017-05-31 09:12:20           3
2017-05-31 09:12:20           3
2017-05-31 09:12:20           3
2017-06-01 00:13:06           0
2017-06-01 00:13:06           0
2017-06-01 00:57:29           0
2017-06-01 00:57:29           3
2017-06-01 00:57:29           3
......
2017-07-01 09:12:20           3
2017-07-01 19:22:20           0
2017-07-01 09:12:20           3
2017-06-01 00:13:06           0
2017-06-01 00:13:06           0
2017-06-01 00:57:29           0
2017-06-01 00:57:29           3
2017-06-01 00:57:29           3
```

Comment: will you please give the output example what are you wanted to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to plot it but I think something like this is what you're looking for.

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
ds = df.groupby(by=[times.dt.hour, times.dt.minute, df.outcome]).count().reset_index(level=['outcome'])
```